# Can Web3 be used to switch between accounts on Metamask programmatically?

Tags: next.js13, web3js, metamask, decentralized-applications

If my currently active account on Metamask is Acc1, and I want to pass the address of Acc2 from a webpage and programmatically switch the active account on Metamask to Acc2, how can this be achieved?

I have explored the Metamask documentation and attempted various approaches, but I haven't found a solution for programmatically switching the active account using web3 and passing the account address from a webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible to do programmatically.

MetaMask only reflects the **user selected** address in the `eth_requestAccounts` method and `selectedAddress` property for security reasons.

Having said that, your app can react to changes by listening to the `accountsChanged` event ([docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/accessing-accounts.html)).

---

*Possible scenario how it could be misused if the switch was allowed programmatically: A user wants to send a transaction from Address 1. Just before opening the MetaMask popup requesting signature, the web app switches the active address to Address 2 along with changing the `value` of the transaction to total balance of Address 2. User overlooks the change and signs the transaction - effectively stealing their Address 2 balance.*